# KeyPress or keyup not firing

Tags: c#, keypress, keydown, keyup

ok i have a c# 2017 net net windows form frmFS the KeyPress, KeyDown or Keyup are not firing.
I created a new project with select the events for keypress, keydown and keyup (put a messageboc.show("bla") in each function it works but my current project nothing. how can i trace the issue.

Comment: win forms (.net 2017, i dbl clicked the key events from the prosperity window and the function was created by .net

Comment: when any place on the form i want to check for the enter (char 13) then fire off a function based on where they have focus ie; if the enter a vendor name in txtVen then hit enter call the function to return the vendor info, or if they enter text in txtCust then and hit enter i want to call the function to return the cust data......

Comment: Please update your question with the details so they don't get lost in the comments. Also please include the code for the event that's not working as you expect it should.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are using a text box for your `KeyDown`, `KeyUp` and `KeyPress` events.

In visual studio in the designer select the text box (or control you are referring to).

Then in the properties pane, select the *Events* tab.

Then look for the `KeyDown`,`KeyPress` and `KeyUp` events.

If the values next to the events are blank then the event in not linked to the control.

[image]

you can double click in the value column to generate the code for the event, or you can see if the event appears in the drop down (if it already exists).

[image]

in the code for the form the event method should be visible.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
 //code here..
}
```